# Asking for help in evaluation of an integral in a research paper

Tags: real-analysis, integration, approximation, approximate-integration

I need Help in evaluating an integral. I have a function $$\rho_0(x)  = \min_{ y\in\mathbb R} \rho( x,y)  =  \min_{0\leq y < 1} \rho(x, y), $$ which is $1$- periodic.

$\rho_0(x) $  can be explicitly given on 0$\leq$  x <1  by

$$\rho_0(x)  = \begin{cases} 0 & \phantom{1/}0\leq x <1/3, \\
1 & 1/3 \leq  x<1/2, \\
2 & 1/2 \leq x <2/3, \\
 3& 2/3 \leq x < 5/6, \\
 4& 5/6 \leq x < 1.
\end{cases}$$

> Integral to be proved is $\int _{0}^1 \rho_0(t) d (\psi(t) + 1/t) $ is approximately equal to 1.29564. ( here $\psi(t) $ = $\frac{ \Gamma'(t) } { \Gamma(t) } $ .

I would be really thankful for any help.

Comment: Using integration by parts simplifies the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By [the properties of the Riemann-Stieltjes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Differentiable_g(x)) integral we have that $$\int_{0}^{1}\rho_{0}\left(t\right)d\left(\psi\left(t\right)+1/t\right)=\int_{0}^{1}\rho_{0}\left(t\right)\left(\psi\left(t\right)+1/t\right)^{\prime}dt$$ hence $$\int_{0}^{1}\rho_{0}\left(t\right)d\left(\psi\left(t\right)+1/t\right)=\int_{1/3}^{1/2}\left(\psi\left(t\right)+1/t\right)^{\prime}dt+2\int_{1/2}^{2/3}\left(\psi\left(t\right)+1/t\right)^{\prime}dt$$ $$+3\int_{2/3}^{5/6}\left(\psi\left(t\right)+1/t\right)^{\prime}dt+4\int_{5/6}^{1}\left(\psi\left(t\right)+1/t\right)^{\prime}dt$$ $${\color{blue}{=\left[\psi\left(t\right)+1/t\right]_{1/3}^{1/2}+2\left[\psi\left(t\right)+1/t\right]_{1/2}^{2/3}+3\left[\psi\left(t\right)+1/t\right]_{2/3}^{5/6}+4\left[\psi\left(t\right)+1/t\right]_{5/6}^{1}}}\approx {\color{red}{1.29564}}.$$